# How to get html5/css3 navigation bar to align at the top?

Tags: html, css

I'm building myself a website on html css etc. (college work so that's a reason why) however I've had struggle with my navigation bar.

The first thing is that it goes to the side of the page which I don't want. I want it at the top like for example the bar at the top of stack overflow. I'm using flexbox for my navigation bar and i like the sizes of each section. My code is:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Georgia;
}
nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #888;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
nav ul {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: top;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  line-height: 56px;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle that we could play around with?

Comment: In your li change your float:top to float:left

Answer (score 3):

```
float:top
```

Is invalid.

The CSS float property can be declared as `left` || `right`, or left as it is

Floating elements can be tricky at the best of times. Instead, you could use something like `display:inline-block` instead.

- [more info on floating elements](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing)
- [All about floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current
>   line. The most interesting characteristic of a float (or "floated" or
>   "floating" box) is that content may flow along its side (or be
>   prohibited from doing so by the 'clear' property). Content flows down
>   the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a
>   right-floated box. The following is an introduction to float
>   positioning and content flow; the exact rules governing float behavior
>   are given in the description of the 'float' property. ~ [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats)

DEMO:

```
nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Georgia;
}
nav {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #888;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
nav ul {  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;
  line-height: 56px;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="forum.html">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: @skylarchaoz: no problem. I have to say I have always been reluctant to use the `float` property as it can cause a few issues doen the line. use display and positioning instead ;)

Comment: @skylarchaoz If this answer addresses your issue please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a great job. I would like to suggest a few things as I have already experienced some problems. 
Use Bootstrap. All you need to do is include a CSS and a JavaScript file and write navbar in class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" and automatically it will be placed at the top with much better looks and having responsive design. It is not difficult at all. It will hardly take and hour or two to understand and implement it in your website.